# How to make a tensorflow dataset input pipeline for multi-class bounding box regression

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, bounding-box

I am making **multi-class bounding box regression** in DICOM images. But the dataset is very big (140 GB). So I can't put all of the training images into memory. I wanted to use a TensorFlow dataset generator from Dicom files and this dataframe.

|  | FilePath | CaseNumber | SliceId | Class | BBox | ImageHeight | ImageWidth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 147353 | 1188164/Seri5/30364335695.dcm | 1188164/Seri5 | 30364335695 | Healthy | nan | 512 | 512 |
| 147354 | 16567/Seri1/36459582300.dcm | 16567/Seri1 | 36459582300 | Healthy | nan | 512 | 512 |
| 147355 | 19242/Seri1/37897787504.dcm | 19242/Seri1 | 37897787504 | Healthy | nan | 512 | 512 |
| 147356 | 16416/Seri2/29526748793.dcm | 16416/Seri2 | 29526748793 | Healthy | nan | 512 | 512 |
| 147357 | 26321/Seri2/29284668905.dcm | 26321/Seri2 | 29284668905 | Abdominal aort anevrizma | 248,177-334,291 | 512 | 512 |

###### How could I make a data input pipeline (`build_dataset` function) using tensorflow in order to be able to use just these lines of code to train my model:

```py
train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)

train_images, train_labels, train_bboxes = build_dataset(train_df)
test_images, test_labels, test_bboxes = build_dataset(test_df)

train_targets = {
    "class_label": train_labels,
    "bounding_box": train_bboxes
}

test_targets = {
    "class_label": test_labels,
    "bounding_box": test_bboxes
}

history = model.fit(
    train_images, train_targets,
    validation_data=(test_images, test_targets),
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=20,)
```

I have tried this:

```py
def build_dataset(dataframe):
    images = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dataframe["FilePath"])
    images = images.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(read_dcm_as_array, [x], [tf.string]))
    
    lb = LabelBinarizer()
    labels = lb.fit_transform(dataframe["Class"])
    labels = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels)

    bboxes = dataframe["BBox"]
    bboxes = bboxes.str.replace(",", "-")
    bboxes = bboxes.str.split("-", expand=True).astype(int)
    bboxes = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(bboxes)

    #targets = tf.data.Dataset.zip(labels, boxes) # this row gives another error :(
    #targets = targets.map(lambda x,y:tf.concat([x,y],axis=-2))
    return images, labels, bboxes
```

But it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using dataset as input.
```